# How do I get the bottom offset of a scroll div from windowheight

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just want offset bottom space of red box, when I was scrolling the body scroll the red box hide some part into the body scroll and I am go to click a button to get a bottom offset of a red box [See image for refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVsGb.jpg)

```js
//want offset bottom of box  after some scroll of body scroll
```

```css
.divHasScroll {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="divHasScroll">
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
  <p> text in box</p>
</div>

<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
<p> text in window scrolling section</p>
```

Comment: Even with your code and the image, I still find it really hard to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: i just want offset bottom space of red box, when i was scrolling the  body scroll the red box hide some part into  the body scroll and i am go to click a button to get a bottom offset of a red box

Comment: I'm not sure but do you mean the height of the scrollable div? So the number of pixels until the bottom of the red box is reached?

Comment: yes you got the right point the number of pixels until the bottom of the red box is reached? when some part of red box is hide after scroll body scrolling, which div will i got to calculate that remain space after the red box div

Answer (score 0):

if your container is the body you can get the offset by this calculation

```
alert($('body').height() - $('.divHasScroll').height());
```

you need the height of the container - the height of the scrollable div.

Offset property is only for top or left, it will not serve you in this situation.

Hope this helps.